# Автодополнение в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Подскажите как в Intellij Idea реализовать такую фичу:

печатаю четыре буквы "psvm" получаю вот такое предложение

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

на автодополнение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`File`⇒`Settings`⇒`Live Templates: other`** там собственно **psvm**.

а вообще всё тоже самое **`psvm`**+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, ну или меняем кнопку в настройках выше.

p.s. собственно там полезно покопаться и сделать свои шаблоны, ну или отредактировать существующие.